# Killer Bunnies Quest / Retrieval Card (Special)

Tags: killer-bunnies

Some debate has taken place in my home concerning the Special card titled Retrieval (Card # 0425)

It says "may be used once by a player to retrieve and immediately use any of the last five run cards played." So...does this mean that the player needs to choose one card out of the five to play? Or does that player get to play any and/or all of the five cards picked up?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't know the game so I won't post as an answer, but I think for most games, the ability to play _all_ five of the last cards played - let alone **seven**, as the card [has also been printed](http://killerbunnies.wikia.com/wiki/Retrieval) - would be so ridiculously overpowered that it would never exist. That, as well as what I think is the more common English meaning of "any of", lead me to say you only get any _one_ card.

Comment: The [Twilight White Bunny Bits](http://killerbunnies.com/PDFfiles/Bits_White.pdf) don't have any additional detail on the Retrieval card.  But in most card games the phrase "any number of cards" would be used if you could pick more than one.

Comment: The wording of the card Benjamin linked to is pretty clear that it's only one card.

Answer (score 1):

**"It’s just one."** -- confirmed by Jeffrey Bellinger, designer of Killer Bunnies, in an email reply.

---

This is an interesting case where a revision of a card's instructions made it much less clear. The original description read:

> May be used once by a player to retrieve and immediately use any Run card from the top seven cards of the discard pile.

In a later series the OP draws their description from (the wiki speculates ZZ series), the description is revised to:

> May be used once by a player to retrieve and immediately use any of the last five Run cards played.

I find myself personally convinced by @GendoIkari's arguments, specifically based on the phrasing "any Run *card*" in the original description. This interpretation is also helped by the phrase "used *once*". Unfortunately, both descriptions are truly ambiguous. If my interpretation of the card's description is correct, this ambiguity could have been resolved by using the phrasing "any *one*" instead of "any". On the other hand, if it was actually intended that you to take all five (or up to seven) cards, the card description could have said something along the lines of "May be used once by a player to retrieve and immediately use or rediscard all of the last five Run cards played."

@Benjamin Cosman's argument is also compelling. It *does* seem overpowered to be able to play 5 (or potentially up to 7) cards: imagine retrieving multiple Choose a Carrot cards. However, using multiple run cards in a turn is not without precedent: [*W Is For Whammy*](http://killerbunnies.wikia.com/wiki/W_Is_For_Whammy) allows you to launch all 5 weapons, but *Retrieval*'s expanded form could be significantly more powerful than the sporadic 5-card hand nature of *Whammy*. Though one never can tell what "balanced" really means for a game like Killer Bunnies... **EDIT:** Turns out you were pretty spot-on in your analysis; Bellinger said it would be "[T]oo powerful that way!"

@BJ Myers point about how the phrase "any number of cards" would have been used if multiple draws were intended *may* be true, but I'm not sure how often I've seen that specific phrase in Killer Bunnies. I think most cards' effects are scoped, so they would be more likely to phrase it using "all" like "all Weapon cards in his five-card hand" (from "W is for Whammy"). The underlying point is the same, though.

Comment: I think you've misread my comment - my point was that Retrieval *doesn't* say "any number of cards."  If you were allowed to pick more than one, it would be more typical to phrase it that way.  Since they didn't use that phrase, I think the designers intended for only 1 card to be chosen.

Comment: @BJMyers Whoops, you're right, I *completely* misinterpreted what you said. I've made an edit.